# Dealing Cards Through a Single Array

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have to write a program to play a game of poker between two 'human' players. I have the main method (dealer) set up to ask for the first player's bet but I haven't been able to figure out how to call upon the Deck class to the deal method. I tried deck.deal(), etc. but nothing seems to go through. Ill post the classes that are involved below and I've taken note of where the code should call upon the deck in the Dealer class

```
public class Dealer
{
    private Deck deck;
    private Player[] players;
    private String n;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static final int NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS = 2;

    /**
     * Default constructor - creates and populates the Player array and the
     * Deck object.
     */
   public Dealer()
   {
      players = new Player[ NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS ]; //IMPORTANT players is the array

      deck = new Deck();

    // populate the array of players

    } // constructor

    /**
     * Outermost level of abstraction for the poker game
     */
    public void play()
    {
      System.out.println("Welcome to Poker!");

      //Getting First Names
      System.out.println("\nEnter first player's name: ");
      String name = scan.nextLine(); 
      players[0] = new Player(name);
      players[0].getName(name);

      //Getting Second Name
      System.out.println("Enter second player's name: ");
      name = scan.nextLine();
      players[1] = new Player(name);
      players[1].getName(name);

      //First Player Goes
      System.out.println(players[0].getName(n) + "'s Turn\n");

      //Bet
      System.out.println("Enter bet: ");
      int bet = players[0].getBet(); //IMPORTANT players is the array and can call Player method as own

      //Able to bet?
      while(!players[0].bet(bet) || !players[1].bet(bet))
      { 
         bet = 20;
         if(!players[0].bet(bet) || !players[1].bet(bet))
         {
            bet = 1;
         }
      }

      //Draw Cards/Deck
      //*****NEED TO DEAL CARDS HERE*****
      //*****DEAL AN ARRAY OF CARD[5] TO EACH PLAYERS[0] AND [1]******

      //Compare

      //Add to winner

      //Add to loser

      //Winner Goes ^^



    } // method play
}    

public class Deck
{
    private int pointer = 0; // indicates the current position in the deck.
                         // This should begin with 0 (the first call)
                         // and increment every time a card is dealt.

   private Card deck[] = new Card[CARDS_IN_DECK];
   private Card tempDeck[] = new Card[CARDS_IN_DECK];
   private Card Cards[] = new Card[5]; 

    public static final int CARDS_IN_DECK = 52;


    /**
     * Instantiate an array of Cards and populate the array with 52 Card 
     * objects.  The face values of the cards should be between 2 - 14.  
     * Values 2 - 10 represent the number cards.  Values 11 - 14 represent 
     * Jack, Queen, King, and Ace, respectively.  The suits should be as 
     * follows: 100 = Clubs, 200 = Diamonds, 300 = Hearts, and 400 = Spades.  
     * See the Card class for more information.
     *
     * You should both shuffle and cut the cards before this method 
     * concludes.
     */
    public Deck()
    {
      int i = 0;
      for(int a = 1; a <= 5; a++)
      {
         for(int b = 2; b <=14; b++)
         {
            deck[i] = new Card(a,b);
         }
      }

      shuffle();
      cut();

    } // default constructor


    /**
     * Cut the deck.  Choose a point in the deck (this can be either random 
     * or fixed) and re-arrange the cards.  For example, if you choose to 
     * cut at position 26, then the 27th - 52nd cards will be placed in the 
     * 1st - 26th positions.  The 1st - 26th cards will be placed in the 
     * 27th - 52nd positions.
     */
    public void cut()
      {
         int cut = 26;
         int a = 0;
         int b = 0;

         for(int i = 0 ; i<cut; i++)
         {
            tempDeck[i] = new Card(a,b);
            tempDeck[i] = deck[i+26];
            tempDeck[i+26] = deck[i];
         }

         deck = tempDeck; 
      }

 // method cut

    /**
     * Deal 5 cards from the deck. Deal out the next 5 cards and return 
     * these in an array.  You will need to maintain a pointer that lets
     * you know where you are in the deck.  You should make sure also
     * to reshuffle and cut the deck and start over if there are not enough 
     * cards left to deal a hand.
     *
     * @return an array of 5 cards
     */
   public Card[] deal(int[] args)
   {
      int i = 0;
      int a = 0;
      int b = 0;
      Cards[i] = new Card(a,b);

      for(i = 0; i < 1; i++)
      {
         Cards[pointer] = deck[pointer];
         pointer++;
      }               

      return Cards; 
         // this is a stub only - replace this!!!!

    } // method deal


    /**
     * Get a card from the deck
     *
     * @param the position of the card you are retrieving
     * @return the card object
     */
   public Card getCard( int card )
   {
      Card oneCard = deck[pointer];
      deck[pointer] = null;
      pointer +=1;

      return oneCard; // this is a stub only - replace this!!!

   } // method getCard


    /**
     * Shuffle the deck.  Randomly re-arrange the cards in the deck. There
     * are plenty of algorithms for doing this - check out Google!!!
     */
      public void shuffle()
      {
         int i, j, k;
         int n = 15;

         for ( k = 0; k < n; k++ )
         {
          i = (int) ( CARDS_IN_DECK * Math.random() );  // Pick 2 random cards
          j = (int) ( CARDS_IN_DECK * Math.random() );  // in the deck

          tempDeck[j] = deck[i];
          tempDeck[i] = deck[j];
          deck = tempDeck;
       }

       pointer = 0;   // Reset current card to deal

      } // end shuffle

} // class Deck


public class Player
{
    private int bet;
    private int chips;
    private int totalChips = 0;

    private Hand hand;
    private String name;


    public static final int START_CHIPS = 100;
    public static final int WINNING_CHIPS = 200;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     * Sets the player's name and the starting number of chips.
     *
     * @param the player's name
     */
   public Player( String n )
   {
         name = n;

         totalChips = START_CHIPS;

   } // constructor


    /**
     * Sets the amount of the bet and decreases the number of chips that 
     * the player has by the number of chips bet. Do not allow bets if 
     * there are not enough chips left.
     *
     * @param the number of chips bet
     * @return true if the bet was successful (there were enough chips)
     */
   public boolean bet( int bet )
   {
      int chipsAB;
      boolean canBet;

      //Get Bet
      getBet();

      //See if player has enough chips for bet
      if(totalChips >= bet)
      {
         canBet = true;
      }
      else
      {
         canBet = false;        
      }

      return canBet; // this is a stub only - replace this!!!!

   } // method bet


    /**
     * Return the number of chips bet
     *
     * @return the number of chips bet
     */              //DONE
    public int getBet()
    {
         int bet;

         bet = scan.nextInt();

         while (bet < 1 || bet > getChips())
         {
            System.out.println("Error. Re-enter bet: ");
            bet = scan.nextInt();
         }

         return bet; // this is a stub only - replace this!!!!

    } // method getBet

    /**
     * Return the number of chips currently held
     *
     * @return the number of chips held
     */
   public int getChips()
   {
      for(int i = 0; i<1; )
      {
         totalChips = START_CHIPS;
      }  


      return totalChips; // this is a stub only - replace this!!!!

   } // method getChips

   public int setChips()
   {
      int playersChips = getChips();
      return playersChips;
   }


    /**
     * Return the player's hand
     *
     * @return the player's hand object
     */
    public Hand getHand()
    {
        return new Hand(); // this is a stub only - replace this!!!!

    } // method getHand


    /**
     * Return the player's name
     *
     * @return the player's name
     */
   public String getName(String name)
   {
      String n = name;          
      return n; // this is a stub only - replace this!!!!

    } // method getName

    /**
     * Indicates whether this player has won
     *
     * @return true if the player has more than the number of winning points
     */
    public boolean hasWon()
    {
         boolean won = false;

         if(chips == 0)
         {
            won = true;
         }

        return won; // this is a stub - replace this!!!

    } // method hasWon


    /**
     * Set the Hand object to the incoming Hand object (this comes from the 
     * Dealer)
     *
     * @param the hand dealt by the dealer
     */
    public void setHand( Hand h )
    {


    } // method setHand


    /**
     * Return the player's name & the number of chips
     *
     * @return the players name & number of chips
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        String nameChips;
        nameChips = (name + totalChips);
        return nameChips; // this is a stub only - replace this!!!

    } // method toString


    /**
     * We won the hand, so increase chips
     *
     * @param the number of chips won
     */
    public int winHand()
    {
      int chipsAB = 0;
      //if(hand.beats(other))
      {
         chipsAB = getChips() + getBet();
      }
      //else
         chipsAB = getChips() - getBet();

      return chipsAB;

    } // method winHand


} // class Player
```

Comment: That is a lot of code for some one to read. I suggest you step through your code in your debugger to get a better understanding of what it is doing.

Comment: the error occurs when I try to call the deck class such as..

Dealer.java:74: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable deal
location: class Deck
      deck = deck.deal[5];

Comment: What error? Does it have a stack trace?  What do you see in your debugger?

Comment: So it is compilation error, not a runtime error?

Comment: yes, it only happens then

Comment: Having a class name and a variable with the same name is very confusing.  Can you change your field to `Card[] cards = ...` ?  Which line is line 74?

Comment: Why do you shuffle only the first 15 cards?

Comment: changed the Card to Cards. And I shuffle 15 based on specifications for the program

Answer (score 0):

The code compiles for me, but I had to

- create a class called `Card` with a constructor `Card(int a, int b)`
- create a class called `Hand`
- ignore the Javadoc errors.
  After `@param` you should have the name of the parameter not `the ...`

Answer (score 0):

The main method wasn't included, but other than that it compiles with a few changes.

I think I can get you going in the right direction but I don't have time to do all the work.  I went a bit further and used Java collections to clarify / ease some of the use.  A bunch of code updates here. Key points are Suit enum, Collections.shuffle, use of ArrayLists for the deck and hands, and the changes in the cut function.  There is also a lot of opportunity for more error and bounds checking.

Stylistically, I'd suggest thinking about your object layout.  Dealer is a specialization of Player, shuffle and cut might better be methods on Dealer (a Deck doesn't do those things to itself).  Anyhow, for this update I didn't touch those things, just something to be aware of.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dealer {
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS = 2;

    private Deck deck;
    private List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>(NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS);

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     * Default constructor - creates and populates the Player array and the Deck object.
     */
    public Dealer() {
        deck = new Deck();
    } // constructor

    /**
     * Outermost level of abstraction for the poker game
     */
    public void play() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Poker!");

        // Getting First Names
        System.out.println("\nEnter first player's name: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        players.add(new Player(name));

        // Getting Second Name
        System.out.println("Enter second player's name: ");
        name = scan.nextLine();
        players.add(new Player(name));

        // First Player Goes
        System.out.println(players.get(0).getName() + "'s Turn\n");

        // Bet
        System.out.println("Enter bet: ");
        int bet = players.get(0).getBet();

        // Able to bet?
        while (!players.get(0).bet(bet) || !players.get(1).bet(bet)) {
            bet = 20;
            if (!players.get(0).bet(bet) || !players.get(0).bet(bet)) {
                bet = 1;
            }
        }

        // Draw Cards/Deck
        // *****NEED TO DEAL CARDS HERE*****
        // *****DEAL AN ARRAY OF CARD[5] TO EACH PLAYERS[0] AND [1]******
        for (Player player : players) {
            player.setHand(deck.deal(5));
        }

        // Compare

        // Add to winner

        // Add to loser

        // Winner Goes ^^

    } // method play
}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player {
    private int chips;
    private int totalChips = 0;

    private List<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
    private String name;

    public static final int START_CHIPS = 100;
    public static final int WINNING_CHIPS = 200;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     * Sets the player's name and the starting number of chips.
     * 
     * @param the
     *            player's name
     */
    public Player(String n) {
        name = n;
        totalChips = START_CHIPS;
    } // constructor

    /**
     * Sets the amount of the bet and decreases the number of chips that the player has by the number of chips bet. Do not allow
     * bets if there are not enough chips left.
     * 
     * @param the
     *            number of chips bet
     * @return true if the bet was successful (there were enough chips)
     */
    public boolean bet(int bet) {
        boolean canBet;

        // Get Bet
        getBet();

        // See if player has enough chips for bet
        if (totalChips >= bet) {
            canBet = true;
        } else {
            canBet = false;
        }

        return canBet; // this is a stub only - replace this!!!!

    } // method bet

    /**
     * Return the number of chips bet
     * 
     * @return the number of chips bet
     */
    // DONE
    public int getBet() {
        int bet;

        bet = scan.nextInt();

        while (bet < 1 || bet > getChips()) {
            System.out.println("Error. Re-enter bet: ");
            bet = scan.nextInt();
        }

        return bet; // this is a stub only - replace this!!!!

    } // method getBet

    /**
     * Return the number of chips currently held
     * 
     * @return the number of chips held
     */
    public int getChips() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1;) {
            totalChips = START_CHIPS;
        }

        return totalChips; // this is a stub only - replace this!!!!

    } // method getChips

    public int setChips() {
        int playersChips = getChips();
        return playersChips;
    }

    /**
     * Return the player's hand
     * 
     * @return the player's hand object
     */
    public List<Card> getHand() {
        return hand;
    } // method getHand

    /**
     * Return the player's name
     * 
     * @return the player's name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    } // method getName

    /**
     * Indicates whether this player has won
     * 
     * @return true if the player has more than the number of winning points
     */
    public boolean hasWon() {
        return (chips > WINNING_CHIPS);
    } // method hasWon

    /**
     * Set the Hand object to the incoming Hand object (this comes from the Dealer)
     * 
     * @param the
     *            hand dealt by the dealer
     */
    public void setHand(List<Card> dealtHand) {
        hand = dealtHand;
    } // method setHand

    /**
     * Return the player's name & the number of chips
     * 
     * @return the players name & number of chips
     */
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + ", Chips: " + chips;
    } // method toString

    /**
     * We won the hand, so increase chips
     * 
     * @param the
     *            number of chips won
     */
    public int winHand() {
        int chipsAB = 0;
        // if(hand.beats(other))
        {
            chipsAB = getChips() + getBet();
        }
        // else
        chipsAB = getChips() - getBet();

        return chipsAB;

    } // method winHand

} // class Player


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Deck {
    public static final int CARDS_IN_DECK = 52;

    private List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>(CARDS_IN_DECK);


    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * Instantiate an array of Cards and populate the array with 52 Card objects. The face values of the cards should be between 2 -
     * 14. Values 2 - 10 represent the number cards. Values 11 - 14 represent Jack, Queen, King, and Ace, respectively.
     * 
     * You should both shuffle and cut the cards before this method concludes.
     */
    public Deck() {
        for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
            // I made the Ace equal to 1, but it's just preference
            for (int value = 2; value <= 14; value++) {
                deck.add(new Card(suit, value));
            }
        }

        Collections.shuffle(deck);
        cut();
    } // default constructor

    /**
     * Cut the deck. Choose a point in the deck (this can be either random or fixed) and re-arrange the cards. For example, if you
     * choose to cut at position 26, then the 27th - 52nd cards will be placed in the 1st - 26th positions. The 1st - 26th cards
     * will be placed in the 27th - 52nd positions.
     */
    public void cut() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int cutPoint = rand.nextInt(deck.size()) + 1;

        List<Card> newDeck = new ArrayList<Card>(deck.size());
        newDeck.addAll(deck.subList(cutPoint, deck.size()));
        newDeck.addAll(deck.subList(0, cutPoint));

        deck = newDeck;
    }

    // method cut

    /**
     * Deal 5 cards from the deck. Deal out the next 5 cards and return these in an array. You will need to maintain a pointer that
     * lets you know where you are in the deck. You should make sure also to reshuffle and cut the deck and start over if there are
     * not enough cards left to deal a hand.
     * 
     * @return an array of 5 cards
     */
    public List<Card> deal(int size) {
        List<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>(size);
        hand.add(deck.remove(0));
        return hand;
    } // method deal

    /**
     * Get a card from the deck
     * 
     * @param the
     *            position of the card you are retrieving
     * @return the card object
     */
    public Card getCard(int position) {
        if (position >= 0 && position < deck.size()) {
            return deck.remove(position);
        }
        else {
            return null; // or throw an exception, or print an error or whatever
        }
    } // method getCard
} // class Deck

public class Card {
    private Suit suit;
    private int value;

    public Card(Suit suit, int value) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

public enum Suit {
    CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES;
}
```